# firestore ordertBy() queries make app can't take data in first request

Tags: firebase, flutter, google-cloud-firestore

This is my main problem

> **firestore ordertBy() queries make app can't take data in first request**

in this case, in simple explanation:

1. After I install my APP on my smartphone that was working normally, I can add data and read that list of my data.
2. But after I uninstall and reinstall my app, that data can't be reached
3. And my app is working normally after I delete orderBy() from my queries.

> *Can any one please help me how to resolve that problem? I need to order my data list*

This is the code of StreamBuilder

```
StreamBuilder(
                  stream: Firestore.instance
                      .collection('murid ' + widget.email)
                      .where('kelas', isEqualTo: widget.kelas)
                      .where('emailGuru', isEqualTo: widget.email).orderBy('no')
                      .snapshots(),
                  builder: (BuildContext context,
                      AsyncSnapshot<QuerySnapshot> snapshot) {
                    if (!snapshot.hasData) {
                      return new Container(
                        child: Column(
                          mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
                          children: <Widget>[
                            Row(
                              mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
                              children: <Widget>[
                                Container(
                                  height: 15.0,
                                  width: 15.0,
                                  child: CircularProgressIndicator(
                                    strokeWidth: 1,
                                  ),
                                ),
                                Padding(
                                  padding: const EdgeInsets.all(8.0),
                                  child: Text(
                                    'Loading ...',
                                    style: TextStyle(fontSize: 18.0),
                                  ),
                                ),
                              ],
                            ),
                            Text(
                              'Data belum tersedia!',
                              textAlign: TextAlign.center,
                            ),
                          ],
                        ),
                      );
                    } else {
                      return Stack(
                        children: <Widget>[
                          Container(
                            height: 55.0,
                            color: Colors.blue[900],
                          ),
                          Padding(
                            padding: const EdgeInsets.only(top: 25.0),
                            child: Container(
                              decoration: BoxDecoration(
                                color: Color.fromRGBO(227, 242, 253, 1.0),
                                borderRadius: BorderRadius.only(
                                    topLeft: Radius.circular(30.0),
                                    topRight: Radius.circular(30.0)),
                              ),
                              child: Stack(
                                children: <Widget>[
                                  Center(
                                    child: Text(
                                      "Pilih Akun",
                                      style: TextStyle(
                                          fontSize: 40.0,
                                          fontWeight: FontWeight.bold,
                                          color: Colors.white54),
                                    ),
                                  ),
                                  DataMurid(
                                    document: snapshot.data.documents,
                                  ),
                                ],
                              ),
                            ),
                          ),
                        ],
                      );
                    }
                  },
                ),
```

and this is the listView.builder

```
ListView.builder(
    itemCount: widget.document.length,
    itemBuilder: (BuildContext context, int i) {
      String no = widget.document[i].data['no'].toString();
      return Container(
        key: new Key(widget.document[i].documentID),
        child: Padding(
          padding: const EdgeInsets.only(left: 20.0, right: 20.0),
          child: Column(
            children: <Widget>[
              Row(
                children: <Widget>[
                  Expanded(
                    child: Container(
                      height: 40.0,
                      decoration: BoxDecoration(
                        color: Colors.blue[900],
                        borderRadius: BorderRadius.only(
                            topLeft: Radius.circular(300.0),
                            bottomLeft: Radius.circular(300.0),
                            topRight: Radius.circular(30.0),
                            bottomRight: Radius.circular(30.0)),
                      ),
                      child: Center(
                        child: Text(
                          no,
                          style: TextStyle(
                              fontSize: 14.0,
                              fontWeight: FontWeight.bold,
                              color: Colors.white),
                        ),
                      ),
                    ),
                  ),
```

I need to order that number because the listview make that number value convert to string, and on the result if number more than 9, example:

my value 'no' is [1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,11,12] , and after I call that value to ListView the output will be like this:

> 1, 10, 11, 12, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9 //without orderBy();

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From the result you get it looks like you're storing the numbers as string values in the database.

For string values Firestore will use lexicographical ordering, meaning that it sorts the way you would sort text. Say that you have text: `"ba"`, `"b"`, `"c"`, "`ca"`. You'd expect them to be sorted like this:

```
"b"
"ba"
"c"
"ca"
```

When you dealing with numbers stored in a string, the database follow the exact same logic. So:

```
"1"
"10"
"11"
"2"
"21"
"3"
```

This may not be what you want, but on the level where the database operates it is fully expected.

---

There are two common solutions for this:

1. Store the values as actual numeric values in the database. This is by far the easiest and in that case the data will order them numerically, instead of lexicographically.
2. Make sure all string values are the same length. If you "pad" the strings with zeroes or spaces so that they're all the same length, the lexicographical ordering will work again:

   ```
   "01"
   "02"
   "03"
   "10"
   "11"
   "21"
   ```

Comment: oh, i see, thanks. but, you know, in default firestore will be sort the data by document name, and the document name is can't be number, thats why i using orderBy(), and the result looks like my explained, if i use orderBy() absolutely my data in firestore is ordered but the data can't be reached in my ListView.builder if i using other device to get data or after i clear my app data in my smartphone, but for solution 2 i think this solution can be used in my documents name, i i'l try it, thanks a lot